# How to create bootable Windows 10 installer USB for PC?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, usb, startup

I've downloaded Windows 10 from Microsoft and want to create a bootable USB stick for a PC. I've tried to flash the image with `dd`, but the stick did not boot.

Then I've flashed the image with bootcamp, it didn't boot either on my PC; it did however boot on my Mac.

How can I create a bootable Windows 10 USB stick to be bootable not on a Mac, but on a PC?

Comment: For me Bootcamp Manager refuses completely, and Etcher says to use the Bootcamp Manager. I can't find a single piece of software for macOS that can actually be used to create Windows 10 install media.

Comment: I'm in this same boat.  Urgently need to re-install Windows 10 since my Win box took a dump this morning and won't repair/recover.  Have tried 4 times now to create a bootable USB... no joy every time despite the endless articles that explain how easy it is.  I don't think a single one of those authors actually tried to use the resulting USB stick to boot their PC.

Answer (score 6):

From [Create a bootable Windows 10 installation USB on macOS](https://jensd.be/1349/windows/create-a-bootable-windows-10-installation-usb-on-macos)

1. download [Windows 10 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10)
2. install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

```bash
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

3. install [wimlib](https://wimlib.net/)

```bash
brew install wimlib
```

4. format USB flash drive as “MS-DOS (FAT)” with “Master Boot Record” scheme. This can be done from the Disk Utility application.
5. open `Win10_21H1_English_x64.iso` and copy files to USB flash drive skipping `install.wim` found at `sources/install.wim` (which is larger than 4GB FAT32 limit)

```
rsync -rv --exclude "install.wim" /Volumes/CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9/ /Volumes/WINDOWS10/
```

6. split `install.wim`

Heads-up: replace `CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9` with actual Windows 10 ISO volume name and `UNTITLED` with USB flash drive volume name.

```bash
wimlib-imagex split /Volumes/CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9/sources/install.wim /Volumes/WINDOWS10/sources/install.swm 4000
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions in [Create a bootable Windows 10 installation USB on macOS](https://jensd.be/1349/windows/create-a-bootable-windows-10-installation-usb-on-macos):

1. **Preparing The USB drive**
   Well, this was simple for my Windows 11 laptop:

   1. You firstly plug the USB drive into your Mac,
   2. Open Finder.
   3. Open the Applications folder (for example by selecting Go > Applications from the menu bar) and look for a folder named "Utilities".
   4. Double-click it and search for the Disk Utility app.
   5. Launch it and in the sidebar, search for your USB drive by name and select it (NOTE: the USB drive's name is originally "Unnamed" unless changed by a user).
   6. You then must find the Erase button located on the top right. Click it and select FAT/FAT32 as the format and “Master Boot Record” as scheme.
   7. When done, double-click the USB drive icon on the desktop to open it.
2. **Preparing The Media**
   Next, head to this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11) and download the ISO file. Once this file is downloaded, mount it by double-clicking it.
3. **Moving Files**
   Follow these instructions **carefully**:

   1. On the ISO file window, open the folder named 'sources'.
   2. Once in the folder, do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and search for the file named `install.wim` and do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+click to deselect it.
   3. Do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
   4. Switch to the USB drive window and make a folder named 'sources', double-click it, and do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
   5. Now, on both the ISO file and USB drive windows, click the back button to go to the root folder and move all files except the 'source' folder from the ISO file window to the USB drive window. When the file moving is done, you can eject and unplug the USB drive.
4. **Installation Process**

   1. Plug the USB drive into the corrupted or empty computer and go to your boot selector by turning on your device and holding <kbd>Esc</kbd> down.
   2. After you see the startup menu, use the key combination that it says beside select boot device or boot selector or boot options.
   3. When you're done, then select the USB drive. Once down click Continue and unplug the USB drive.
   4. Plug the USB drive into the Mac, open Disk Utility again select the USB drive, erase it but this time choose ExFAT as the format. Once done, copy all the files from the ISO drive into the USB drive.
   5. Eject the USB drive and plug it into the Windows machine again.
   6. Then Click Install or the button in the middle of the screen and **keep the USB plugged in until you have finished setup and are at the Desktop**.
5. **Final Setup**
   Finish setting up Windows and done!

Comment: Hi @SadGaming and welcome to Ask Different! This question is about making a Windows 10 USB installer but your answer (except for the link at the top) addresses making a Windows 11 USB installer. Perhaps you could edit the steps and the download link to refer to Windows 10 specifically?

If you like, you could also add an addendum explaining that the same process could be applied using a Windows 11 ISO.

Comment: Excuse me, but these steps should work for both versions, even should work for windows 8 or 8.1 but you would need a product key. As for A Windows 10/11 are Identical except the Version Number and Some UI in the OS itself.

Answer (score -1):

### Step 1----------------------------

Get an 8GB [USB Flash Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) as this is easily to make on it even though it may seem small, but Windows [USB Flash Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) Install/Windows Install via [USB Flash Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) only takes about 4GB to 7GB of space.

**SAVE FILES THAT ARE IMPORTANT TO YOU IF YOU ARE FORMATTING A USB FLASH DRIVE IN USE**
You Need to format this [USB Flash Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) to [FAT32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32), as come computer do not support [exFat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) on [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) or when booting up from my experience. Once Formatted you have prepared the [USB Flash Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) to add files to it.

### Step 2----------------------------

You now need a separate computer, a computer that you can download and move files. Not a phone. Examples:

- Windows PC
- MacBook (Air, Pro, or Regular Will Work)
- Friend's Computer

**Windows PC ____________**

- **Install Windows 10/11**

After, you have to plug in the [USB Flash Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) in the computer, open your browser (Firefox, Microsoft Edge, Chrome) and
download [Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) or [Windows 11](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11). **MAKE SURE YOUR PC IS COMPATIBLE WITH WINDOWS 11** Download the Media Install Media Creation Tool for WINDOWS ONLY (Required for Windows 10 install), after downloading the tool installer, download it, run the new exe file. Once running click Setup, then click create installation media. Click next and select USB Flash Drive, wait until downloaded and done!  You have made a WIU (Windows Installer USB) on a Windows PC!

**MacBook________________**

- **Install Windows 10/11**

**YOU WILL REQUIRE A WINDOWS EXE RUNNER/EMULATOR LIKE WINE**

Download Wine if necessary. and Load the EXE File From WINDOWS MEDIA CREATION TOOl to download WMCT and open it using wine as well. Now You May continue the steps above that are for Windows PC, This is an extra step you NEED TO take to download on MacBook!